# Finding roots with seemingly no algebraic way

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, roots

I have a graph of:

$$y = \frac{x^3 + 2x^2 - 4}{x^2}$$

and I have to find the x-intercept.

So I have the equation $(x^2)(x+2)-4 = 0$

And then I don't know what to do. Not sure if we can use calculators but will use them if there is no other way. Thanks.

Comment: One could use the Cardano Formula (please see Wikipedia). But it is a messy business, and usually one solves such equations numerically, unless there is an "obvious" root, which is not the case here. Usually when making up exercises one tries to make sure roots are simple. You might check whether the cubic is really the right one.

Comment: Yeah this graph equation was given to us like that, so I'm sure it's right. Thanks for the input

Comment: Am I the only one who reads $y=x$ right now? There's something weird with this question.

Comment: I suppose that it is $y = \frac{x^3 + 2x^2 - 4}{x^2}$

Comment: Seems like someone edited and missed out an $x$. Should be correct now

Comment: As André Nicolas wrote, Cardano could be tedious. For your case, the $x$ intercept is given by $$\frac{1}{3} \left(-2+\sqrt[3]{46-6 \sqrt{57}}+\sqrt[3]{46+6
   \sqrt{57}}\right)$$ which is not very nice. But by inspection, you probably noticed that the solution is very close to $1$. So, use Newton for a couple of steps : after the first iteration, you have $8/7$, after the second $823/728$ which is $1.13049$ while the exact value should be $1.13050$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Once upon a time, I even made some money from the "Cardano" formula (well, I am lying, it was from the Viete trigonometric formula). For an early primitive spreadsheet, someone needed a **formula** for the roots of a cubic (well, it wasn't exactly a cubic, but it reduced to a cubic).

Comment: Do you know numerical analysis, or can you use it? If so, you can find the root up to the desired places of decimal. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^3+2x^2-4$$
$$f(0)=-4,f(1)=-1,f(2)=12$$
Since $f(1)f(2)<0$ there is one root in between.

Now this is messy:

$f(1.5)=3.375+4.5-4>0$
So root is in between $1$ and $1.5$

$f(1.25)=1.078>0,f(1.125)=-0.0449<0$

So approximate value of $x\approx1.1(8)$ satisfies your equation, with exact value at $x=1.13039543476\cdots$ seems close, or you may iterate further if you want

Comment: I know the root is between 1 and 2 I just don't know how to find what the root is exactly

Comment: @JonnathanBaquero see edit

Comment: Ah so just keep narrowing it down I guess. Not that mathematic but oh well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace $x=\frac{2}{y}$ in equation $x^3+2x^2-4=0$ and get 
$$
\left(\frac{2}{y}\right)^3+2\left(\frac{2}{y}\right)^2-4=0
$$
and after simplifications
$$
y^3-2y-2=0
$$
Now use the Cardamo's formula for cubic equation $y^3+py+q=0$
$$
y=\sqrt[3\,]{-\frac{p}{2}+\sqrt{\left(-\frac{p}{2}\right)^2+\left(-\frac{q}{3}\right)^3}}
+ \sqrt[3\,]{-\frac{p}{2}-\sqrt{\left(-\frac{p}{2}\right)^2+\left(-\frac{q}{3}\right)^3}}
$$
Now (as suggested by  André Nicolas) follow the instructions on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) to manipulate the formula and get a algebric representation of roots.